# How to get Flow Coroutine in Java with RxJava

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

I need to get a Coroutine Flow in my Java app. I try to test with RxJava but it's dosn't work for me

```
Single<Object> collect = Flowable.just(mContextServer.observeAllMessages()).collect(new Collector<Flow<Message>, Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Supplier<Object> supplier() {
                Log.d(TAG, "supplier");
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public BiConsumer<Object, Flow<Message>> accumulator() {
                Log.d(TAG, "accumulator");
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public BinaryOperator<Object> combiner() {
                Log.d(TAG, "combiner");
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Function<Object, Object> finisher() {
                Log.d(TAG, "finisher");
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
                Log.d(TAG, "characteristics");
                return null;
            }
        });
```

someone would have a solution ?

Comment: Your example makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve exactly? What is `mContextServer.observeAllMessages()`?